# executing a .bat file in background and daemon mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, background

I want to create a .bat file and attach it to the boot processes so everytime I start the computer I wont have to execute the file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. What exactly is your question? Did you try putting the batch file in the autostart folder?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Task Scheduler.

Create a new task (don't use a basic task), for the trigger drop down (the default is scheduled) to At Startup.

You'll need to configure a user account to execute the batch file (likely there is no one logged in yet).

Comment: I wanna do it with a batch script, the final idea is to plug in an usb with autostart and then run the file in background and daemon mode. I wont have acess to interface is just to automate security testings just plugging an usb.

Comment: Firstly device change is a completely different trigger.. Secondly what do you mean by "I wanna do it with a batch script": because your question is about executing a batch on boot, what to put in the batch is a different question.